# Single emit on observable's onNext in rx-java 1.2

Tags: rx-java

Suppose

```
PublishSubject<Void> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Single<Integer> single = Single.just(0);
single.subscribe(anySubscriber);
```

How could I make `single` emit value **only after calling** `subject.onNext(null)`?

It is not a case for `repeatWhen` - I do not need to resubscribe on single. Just want to defer emition till some moment, and trigger it manually.

I tried

```
subject.flatMap(nothing -> single.toObservable()).toSingle().subscribe(anySubscriber);
```

But in this case anySubscriber is never called, because subject does not complete.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In short - the solution is `delaySubscription()`.
Should be used like following:

```
PublishSubject<Void> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Single<Integer> single = Single.just(0);
single.delaySubscription(subject).subscribe(anySubscriber);
```

Then, somewhere in code, when ready to emit single, call

```
subject.onNext(null);
```